# does root node rule cascase to child and its subchild in firebase?

Tags: firebase-security

In the docs its told that rules cascade and children can't revoke the privileges  but later in chat example root read and write rules are default to false,so why it doesn't cascade?
[Doc link](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-advanced-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

When we say that *rules cascade*, read it as **permissions cases**. Once you have permission to read a node, you cannot take that permission away at a lower level.

So you *can* start with `".read": false` at the top-level and then allow reads lower (snippet from the [Firebase documentation on security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-advanced-example)):

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    "room_names": {
      // the room names can be enumerated and read
      // they cannot be modified since no write rule
      // explicitly allows this
      ".read": true,
```

But the opposite does not work. You cannot say that nobody is allowed to see a specific room name once you've said that every can see all room names:

```
// THIS SNIPPET WILL NOT WORK
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    "room_names": {
      // the room names can be enumerated and read
      // they cannot be modified since no write rule
      // explicitly allows this
      ".read": true,
      "my_secret_room": {
          // THIS WILL NOT WORK
          // since we've said that every can read all room names
          // we cannot take that permission away anymore
          ".read": false
      }
```